# resistance calculator saying index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to write a program that gathers all resistors, calculates, then gets voltage and then calculates current. Here is what I have so far:

```
resistors = [0]


def ObtainResistors(resistors):
    for i in range(1, 8):
            value = int(input('please enter resistor %d:' % i))
            resistors.append(value)
            return


def TotalResistance(resistors):
    rt1 = ((resistors[2] * resistors[3]) / (resistors[2] + resistors[3]))
    print(rt1, 'ohms')
    rt2 = (rt1 + resistors[4])
    print(rt2, 'ohms')
    rt3 = ((rt2 * resistors[5]) / (rt2 + resistors[5]))
    print(rt3, 'ohms')
    rt4 = (rt3 + resistors[7])
    print(rt4, 'ohms')
    rt5 = ((rt4 * resistors[6]) / (rt4 + resistors[6]))
    print(rt5, 'ohms')
    rt6 = (rt5 + resistors[1])
    print(rt6, 'ohms')
    rt = (rt1 + rt2 + rt3 + rt4 + rt5 + rt6)
    print(rt,  'ohms')
    return


ObtainResistors(resistors)
print(resistors)
TotalResistance(resistors)
print(resistors)
```

This is what i get when i run

```
please enter resistor 1:1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Introduction_to_Python/RESISTOR COURSEWORK.py", line 31, in <module>
    TotalResistance(resistors)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Introduction_to_Python/RESISTOR COURSEWORK.py", line 12, in TotalResistance
    rt1 = ((resistors[2] * resistors[3]) / (resistors[2] + resistors[3]))
IndexError: list index out of range
[0, 1]

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only reading 1 resistor value if you `return` in loop.

Move the `return` out of loop, or remove it since Python doesn't require explicit return and you're not returning a value:

```
def ObtainResistors(resistors):
    for i in range(1, 8):
        value = int(input('please enter resistor %d:' % i))
        resistors.append(value)
    # return
```